# Is it possible to select data in the reducer and put those data into one of states?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, redux

I have an order state.

In order state, there are states of followings.

```
const initialState = {
 channel: null,
 order: {},
 fetching:true,
 menu: [],
 categories: [],
 subcategories: [],
 currentCategoryId: 1,
 currentSubcategoryId: 5,
 currentMenu: [],
};
```

So `menu` is all lists of food item in the database. `categories` are list of menu categories and `subcategories` are list of all subcategories.

Now when a user clicks category selector, it changes value of `currentCategoryId` and it shows items with selected category_id. For `currentSubcategoryId` works same with `currentCategoryId`.

So now I am trying to make pagination for the menu. In order to make pagination for menu, I need to calculate how many menu are there based on `category_id` or `subcategory_id`, for example, when `currentCategoryId` is 1, how many menus with `category_id = 1`are there. So I made `currentMenu`. What I am trying to do with `currentMenu` is that when a user clicks category selector to change `currentCategoryId`, it changes value in reducer and gets menu of which `category_id` equals to changed `currentCategoryId`.

```
case Constants.CHANGE_CATEGORY:
        return {...state, currentCategoryId: action.categoryId, currentMenu: state.menu.map((menu) => {
            if (currentCategoryId === category_id) {
                // Put results of if statement to currentMenu array..
            }
        })};
```

So I made reducer case like above, but I do not know how can I insert results of if statement values to `currentMenu` array... How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you right so you can use a really great package called 'react-addons-update'.

So you can, for example, do something like:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update'
...
...
case Constants.CHANGE_CATEGORY:
    ...
        if (currentCategoryId === category_id) {
            ...
            return update(state, {
            $merge: { [currentMenu]: value }
        });
            ...
        }
    })};
```

Another useful commands like $merge is $set.

You can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)